# Access to a shared Chatter File's Public file raw data URL

Tags: rest-api, chatter-file

I've been trying to setup an app that will directly link to public chatter files.

The best I have been able to get so far is the Flash applet available from the fileViewUrl link, retrievable with the

> /services/data/v31.0/chatter/files/{FILE-ID}/file-shares/link

endpoint. But ideally, I would have a direct link to the file that can be downloaded from there. Basically, I'm looking for the link to the file that is retrieved when you click "Download" on the Flash applet.

Is that something that the Salesforce API's support? Or am I forced to manually download the Base64 encoded file, and host it?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?